# People's names as names for genitalia?

Tags: etymology, slang, word-usage

How did Peter, the surname, Johnson, and the nicknames for William(Willy) and Richard(Dick), come to mean penis?  Was the first instance of these usages, related to a specific person?

Are there more examples in this area? Is this exclusive to English?

Comment: Original title was reference to a Billy Joel parody song. Current title is more precise but hardly as funny.

Comment: Somewhat related: [History/connection/origin of using names as verbs/nouns?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/history-connection-origin-of-using-names-as-verbs-nouns)

Comment: There are some popular examples in Portuguese (pt_PT) too, specially for common names. For instance `Zé` (which is short for `José`) is sometimes used as `Zézinho` (sort of: the little `Zé`) to refer to the penis.

Comment: so what about female genitalia as well?

Comment: @n611x007 Fanny.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Etymonline:

> **[peter](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Peter)** Slang for "penis" is attested from 1902, probably from identity of first syllable.
>
> **[johnson](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=johnson)** "penis," 1863, perhaps related to British slang John Thomas, which has the same meaning (1887).
>
> **[dick](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dick)**
> "fellow, lad, man," 1550s, rhyming nickname for Rick, short for Richard, one of the commonest English names, it has long been a synonym for "fellow," and so most of the slang senses are probably very old, but naturally hard to find in the surviving records. The meaning "penis" is attested from 1891 in British army slang.

**Edit**:
*The Lover's Tongue: A Merry Romp Through the Language of Love and Sex* by Mark Steven Morton has an entire chapter on the subject, "[The Long and the Short of It: Words for the Penis and Its Attendant Parts](http://books.google.com/books?id=tnwAlLgWEhAC&pg=PA106&dq=names%20for%20penis&hl=en&ei=o5LGTZCeNZK-tgfw4NmLBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CFsQ6AEwBQ#v=snippet&q=he%20Long%20and%20the%20Short%20of%20It:%20Words%20for%20the%20Penis%20and%20Its%20Attendant%20Parts&f=false)," that begins with an impressive five-page collection of names. Here's what he has on the names in question:

> A few years after Edward Ward published his poem, the name *Roger* also came to denote penis. This was, in fact, the first of several male given names to be bestowed on that part of the male anatomy—*Thomas* followed in 1811, *Dick* in 1891, *Peter* in 1902 and *Willie* in 1905. To some extent, the application of these names to the penis occurred simply because those names were considered typically male, the kind of name that Joe Blow or any Tom, Dick or Harry might have. [...]  With *Peter*, however, there may be an additional reason why it came to denote penis: that name derives from the Greek *petros*, meaning *stone*, a material whose hardness might recall the firmness of an erection. The word is still used with that stony sense in the name *saltpeter*, a chemical compound that was once given to young men and soldiers to reduce their sexual ardour. [...] Last names, too, have been bestowed on the penis, such as *Johnson*, which dates back to the mid nineteenth century but has recently gained wide currency.

Comment: Only your answer for Peter, really speaks to the how.  Any more specific info on why those particular names? Why not George, or Chester?

Comment: This one's not a current slang, but it's certainly interesting: Roger used to also mean “penis”, as it's derived from PG hroði+gār, meaning *fame-spear*.

Comment: @Jonathan and it sort of still does in the sense that you can 'Roger' somebody.

Comment: @Sam: Added edit.

Comment: I almost wonder about Frank.

Answer (score 1):

William Byrd II of Virginia, in his secret diary, speaks often of rogering his wife or giving her a flourish.  So the word seems to have been used more as a verb in early America.

However, there seems to be no clear answer as to how the use of *dick* came to be; only when and generally by whom.

Comment: I don't get 'flourish'. Is 'Flour' somebody's name?

Comment: @Mitch [Yes](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_(Bambi)).

Comment: Ah, so that would be [Colonel William Byrd II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Byrd_II) (28 March 1674 – 26 August 1744) of Virginia.  Yes, that is a long time ago.